# Jquery UI: How to indicate succesful drop of a draggable onto a sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm currently stuck trying to figure this out.

I have two lists; one is a draggable list, the other both sortable and droppable. I would like to indicate a succesful drop into my sortable list by prepending the original list item with a bit of code which shows that it has been added to the other list. I can get this to work by calling the stop function on the draggable (it's commented out on my fiddle), the problem is that it also does this to items with invalid drops or misses.

It seems that any function (event, ui) on the sortable and droppable only refer to the item that ends up the the second list. I need to update the item in the original "dragged" list.

Snippets I have:

```
<div id="tabs2" class="list pre">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#otherlist">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#cdaMed">2</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="otherlist" class=".ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel">
    <ul class="list">
      <li>Simvastatin 20 mg tablet by mouth once daily</li>
      <li>Lorazepam 0.5 mg tablet by mouth three times daily</li>
      <li>Insulin Glargine (or Lantus) 10 units once daily</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="cdaMed" class=".ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel">
    <ul class="list">
      <li>Insulin Glargine (or Lantus) 10 units once daily</li>
      <li>Metoprolol Tartrate 50 mg tablet by mouth once daily</li>                   
      <li>Warfarin Sodium 5 mg tablet by mouth once daily Monday, Wednesday, Friday, Sunday</li>
      <li>Warfarin Sodium 2.5 mg tablet by mouth once daily Tuesday, Thursday, Saturday</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="scratch">
  <ul id="medsScr" class="list">
    <li><a class="close"></a>Simvastatin 20 mg tablet by mouth once daily</li>
    <li><a class="close"></a>Lorazepam 0.5 mg tablet by mouth three times daily</li> 
    <li><a class="close"></a>Insulin Glargine (or Lantus) 10 units once daily</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My jquery:

```
$('#tabs, #tabs2, #tabs3').tabs({ active: 1 });

$( "#cdaMed .list li" ).draggable({ 
        cursor: "move", 
        helper: "clone", 
        opacity: 0.7,
        connectToSortable: "#medsScr",
        stack: ".list",
        revert: "invalid"

        /*,
        stop: function( event, ui ) {
            var $target = $(event.target);

            $target.prepend('<span class="drug"></a>');
            $target.draggable('disable');

        } */
});


$('#medsScr').sortable({
  forcePlaceholderSize: true,
  cursor: "move",
  connectWith: "#cdaMed",
  receive: function(e, ui) {

    var undo = $(this).siblings('.sc_menu').find('.undo');
    var start = $(this).siblings('.sc_menu').find('.so');
    var newitem = $(this).children('li.ui-draggable');

    //undo.addClass('on');
    //start.addClass('on');
    newitem.prepend('<a class="close"></a>').removeClass('ui-draggable');
  }

});

 $('#medsScr.list li').droppable({
    accept: ".ui-draggable",
    addClass: false,
    tolerance: "touch",
    drop: function( d, ui ) {
        var $drug = $(event.target);
        $drug.prepend('<span class="drug"></a>');
    }

});
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhottle/9DU9v/1/) for this.

Thanks, any thoughts on how to fix this greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could use ui.item in your receive function. Like this $(ui.item).prepend('<span class="drug"></a>');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution would be to have a `var $target` in the outer block, and do:

```
start: function( event, ui ) {
   $target = $(event.target);
}
```

Then, you can move these lines to `receive()`:

```
$target.prepend('<span class="drug"></a>');
$target.draggable('disable');
```

Alternately, note that if drop is successful, `receive()` will be called before `stop()`. So, you could have a `var success` in the outer block that gets set to `false` in `start()` and `true` in `receive()`; then check in `stop()` if it is `true`. If so, then you know the drag was received.

Comment: Awesome, that did it!!